# Android Studio Tab Spacing

Tags: android-studio

How can I change spacing in **Android Studio** to use tabs instead of spaces? I tried **Preference -> Editor** but I don't see the option there. I'm using Android Studio for Mac

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Type in 'spac' in the search panel of the settings view.

You will find `Editor` -> `Code Style`->`Java`->`Tabs and Indents`->`Use tab character`.

Comment: is there any way to replace the spaces I have written so far with tabs or should I do it manually?

Comment: Use the auto format. It will change other stuff too unfortunately.

Comment: For those wondering, auto-format is:
CTRL + ALT + L (Win/ Linux), and OPTION + CMD + L (Mac)

Comment: There is a way other than auto-format. Under Edit->Convert Indents.

Comment: There is also the setting `Editor`->`Code Style`:`Detect and use existing file indents for editing` - this was throwing me off because the file already had spaces and so future indenting also had spaces.

Comment: @Terence thats great! But it doesn't catch `int a; __here_are_spaces__  // this is an int`

Comment: I was trying to set this for Kotlin files, but Kotlin didn't appear as a file type under Editor > Code Style until I searched for "kotlin" instead of "space." Now Kotlin appears whenever I open the preferences.

Answer (score 5):

This is a little weird, but others may have the same issue I did.

Yes, follow the above directions, and do the normal changes in the config file.  And guess what? it looks like it's still making spaces instead of tabs, even though the settings say TABS, not spaces!

Turn on "show whitespaces" (Editor -> General -> Appearance).  And then turn it off.  Looks like this is enough to reset the editor so that it is now following the rules you set in the preferences.

Comment: Exactly the problem I was having and this worked. That bug should definitely be fixed.

Comment: yeah, it works now after these weird steps. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @LuckyLukeSkywalker I'm guessing that there are some strange state variables in Android Studio that are conflicting.  I can only suggest playing around (clearing caches, removing or modifying config files, etc.) until you find something that works.  Good luck!