# Android studio use tab character but it show with space still

Tags: settings, android-studio-2.2

This is my setting:

[image]

but my code still show white space not the upper style:

[image]

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129071/android-studio-this-file-is-indented-with-tabs-instead-of-4-spaces/42593333#42593333 I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have solve this question.This is my steps:
First,open your Editor->Code Style,then uncheck the Detect and using existing file indents for editing option;
Second,open your Editor->Code Style->java , check the use tab character option.
You can try.

Comment: I solved my problem through modifying the keymap.The manner is coverting indents include to tap and to space.I transfer the space to tap in this way.