# How to add/remove levels of indentation on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I know there is an option for auto-indentation but I’d like to have a bit of control on how many the levels of indentation I have, or at least to be able to set those parameters somewhere.

This is what I get with auto indentation:

```
gl.glClearColor(Color.red(mBackgroundColor) / 255f,
        Color.green(mBackgroundColor) / 255f,
        Color.blue(mBackgroundColor) / 255f,
        Color.alpha(mBackgroundColor) / 255f);
```

This is what I want:

```
gl.glClearColor(Color.red(mBackgroundColor) / 255f,
    Color.green(mBackgroundColor) / 255f,
    Color.blue(mBackgroundColor) / 255f,
    Color.alpha(mBackgroundColor) / 255f);
```

Currently I have to select one by one the three lines below `gl.glClearColor(...` and remove the additional tab character by hand.

[image]

---

**Edit**

These are my settings, I'm using tab characters with smart tabs disable, but I still get two tab characters in some cases.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio "This file is indented with tabs instead of 4 spaces"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129071/android-studio-this-file-is-indented-with-tabs-instead-of-4-spaces)

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler Edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to **Settings -> Editor -> Code Style**
2. Unmark the checkbox ***Enable EditorConfig support***
3. Go to **Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java**
4. Change the value of ***Continuation Indent*** as u need

Comment: I disabled the option but I'm still getting the same behavior, thanks.

Comment: unmark the checkbox "Enable EditorConfig support",,,and then try changing the value of "Continuation Indent" in settings window u posted