# Using tab identation instead of spaces on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2

Just trying to use `tab-indentation` on `Android Studio 2.2.2`

I followed the instructions I found on this thread:

[Android Studio "This file is indented with tabs instead of 4 spaces"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129071/android-studio-this-file-is-indented-with-tabs-instead-of-4-spaces)

But these instructions work only for new documents I create after setting that configuration but for previously created documents the `space-indentation` persists.

How can I configure all the files on my project to `tab-indentation`? for files before and after the `tab-indentation` configuration on the link above?

Answer (score 2):

After changing the settings you have to reformat your codes, you can do this one by one by opening the file and pressing (Command + Option + L) shortcut or right click on your src folder and selecting `Reformat Code` option:
[image: Reformat Code menu]

You can check the result by selecting `View -> Active Editor -> Show Whitespaces` from the menu:
[image: show Whitespaces menu]

which would be something like this:
[image: Tabbed code sample]