# How to make android studio not add white space automatically after press enter in new line

Tags: git, android-studio

Android studio add a couple of white space after press enter in new line.
[image]

How to cancel this behavior because when I execute "git diff", there is a red block in that place, which is not allow when review in gerrit.

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any code formatter try to check in that file or review your code style hope this helps: [Android Studio "This file is indented with tabs instead of 4 spaces"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129071/android-studio-this-file-is-indented-with-tabs-instead-of-4-spaces)